# How to use CompletableFuture.thenCompose() when returning entities from repositories?

Tags: java, return, completable-future, spring-async

I started working with `CompletableFuture` in Spring Boot, and I'm seeing in some places that the usual repository methods return `CompletableFuture <Entity>` instead of `Entity`.

I do not know what is happening, but when I return instances of `CompletableFuture` in repositories, the code runs perfectly. However when I return entities, the code does not work asynchronously and always returns `null`.

Here is an example:

```
@Service
public class AsyncServiceImpl{
    /** .. Init repository instances .. **/

    @Async(AsyncConfiguration.TASK_EXECUTOR_SERVICE)
    public CompletableFuture<Token> getTokenByUser(Credential credential) {
        return userRepository.getUser(credential)
            .thenCompose(s -> TokenRepository.getToken(s));
    }
}

@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Async(AsyncConfiguration.TASK_EXECUTOR_REPOSITORY)
    public CompletableFuture<User> getUser(Credential credentials) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
            new User(credentials.getUsername())
        );
    }       
}

@Repository
public class TokenRepository {

    @Async(AsyncConfiguration.TASK_EXECUTOR_REPOSITORY)
    public CompletableFuture<Token> getToken(User user) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
            new Token(user.getUserId())
        );
    }
}
```

The previous code runs perfectly but the following code doesn't run asynchronously and the result is always `null`.

```
@Service
public class AsyncServiceImpl {
    /** .. Init repository instances .. **/

    @Async(AsyncConfiguration.TASK_EXECUTOR_SERVICE)
    public CompletableFuture<Token> requestToken(Credential credential) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> userRepository.getUser(credential))
            .thenCompose(s -> 
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> TokenRepository.getToken(s)));
    }
}

@Repository
public class UserRepository {
    @Async(AsyncConfiguration.TASK_EXECUTOR_REPOSITORY)
    public User getUser(Credential credentials) {
        return new User(credentials.getUsername());
    }       
}

@Repository
public class TokenRepository {
    @Async(AsyncConfiguration.TASK_EXECUTOR_SERVICE)
    public Token getToken(User user) {
        return new Token(user.getUserId());
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this second code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the Spring @Async Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html):

> the return type is constrained to either `void` or `Future`

and it is also [further detailed in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async):

> In the simplest case, the annotation may be applied to a `void`-returning method.
>
> […]
>
> Even methods that return a value can be invoked asynchronously. However, such methods are required to have a `Future` typed return value. This still provides the benefit of asynchronous execution so that the caller can perform other tasks prior to calling `get()` on that Future.

In your second example, your `@Async`-annotated methods do not return a `Future` (or `ListenableFuture` and `CompletableFuture` which are also supported). However, Spring has to run your method asynchronously. It can thus only behave as if your method had a `void` return type, and thus it returns `null`.

As a side note, when you use `@Async`, your method will already run asynchronously, so you shouldn't use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` inside the method. You should simply compute your result and return it, wrapped in [`CompletableFuture.completedFuture()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-) if necessary. If your method is only composing futures (like your service that simply composes asynchronous repository results), then you probably don't need the `@Async` annotation. See also [the example from the Getting Started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/#_create_a_github_lookup_service).